# How to combine several getElementsByName into one operation?

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript and I need to combine them into one operation if possible.

```
    document.getElementsByName("last_name")[0].required = true;
    document.getElementsByName("company_name")[0].required = true;
    document.getElementsByName("companyIndustry")[0].required = true;
    document.getElementsByName("company_address")[0].required = true;
    document.getElementsByName("email")[0].required = true;
    document.getElementsByName("phone")[0].required = true;
    document.getElementsByName("products")[0].required = true;
    document.getElementsByName("comments")[0].required = true;
```

Comment: Use a loop and an array

Comment: btw, why not take `id` instead?

Comment: Altough I can include them, the form does not have ids. I am using Kwes forms and a WYSIWYG page builder that accepts html and javascript but sanitizes the html and its not allowing me to directly add the required or required="true" attribute.

Comment: Without worrying about how to make it happen, what do you want your final syntax to look like? is `make_required('last_name', 'company_name', ...)` _combined_ enough for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an array of classes with a loop can reduce redundant code:

```
const classes = ["last_name", "company_name", ...];

for (const className of classes) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0].required = true;
}
```

And like @nina-scholz suggested you might want to use ids instead:

```
const ids = ["last_name", "company_name", ...];

for (const id of ids) {
    document.getElementById(id).required = true;
}
```

Comment: Are classes better than names in this case? Since they already have names in their form elements.